# How can I check instanceof in this TypeScript code at runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zeromq

I'm trying to check whether a variable is an instance of ZeroMQ's `Socket` at runtime.  In JavaScript, this works:

```
doCheck(input) {
    if (input instanceof zmq.Socket) {
        console.log("Is a socket.");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Is not a socket.");
    }
}
```

However in TypeScript, it complains about `zmq.Socket`, saying it hasn't been exported from the type definition file.  That file defines `Socket` as an interface, so it isn't the right type for checking whether it's an instance.  How can I get the `instanceof` check to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `zmq.Socket` is exported as an interface you can't use `instanceof` on this type. You could mess around in the implementation to see what class is actually instantiated but it would be messy and unreliable.

An option would be to check that several methods that you expect exist on the object and put it in a type guard function so you can change it later if needed:

```
import * as zmq from 'zmq'

function isSocket( sock: any ) : sock is zmq.Socket {
    var castSock = sock as zmq.Socket;
    // If it has all the methods it's probably a zmq.Socket
    return castSock.getsocketopt !== undefined
        && castSock.connect      !== undefined
        && castSock.disconnect   !== undefined
        && castSock.close        !== undefined;
}

function doCheck(input) {
    if (isSocket(input) ) {
        input.close() // input is of a type zmq.Socket
        console.log( "Is a ZeroMQ Socket instance." );
    }
    else {
        console.log( "Is not a ZeroMQ Socket instance." );
    }
}
```

---

### Edit:

If the `instanceof` code works in plain JS that means the definition is wrong and `Socket` should actually be a class. You could correct it and submit it to the project, but in the meantime you could add the following code in the file you use `instanceof`:

```
declare module 'zmq' {
    export class Socket {}
}

function doCheck(input : zmq.Socket | string) {
    if (input instanceof zmq.Socket) {
        input.close() // input is of type zmq.Socket
         console.log( "Is a ZeroMQ Socket instance." );
    }
    else {
        console.log( "Is not a ZeroMQ Socket instance." );
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to just go back to the functionality that JavaScript provides?

Comment: @Jez would `instanceof` work in plain js ? if yes the definition is wrong and should be corrected

Comment: Yes it works in plain JS.  How would I fix the definition?  At the moment it is an interface.

Comment: Ok, will fix the answer in a sec

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check `instanceof` interface, because it is only type known to Typescript. After compilation all interfaces and types are removed, so in executed javascript code there are no types/interfaces that you can rely on. If you want to check `instanceof` you need to provide some kind of constructor function.

You can check playground snippet that shows how it works [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20XD%20implements%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%202%20%7D%20instanceof%20Bar)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%202%20%7D%20instanceof%20XD)%3B%0D%0A). Note that there is no interface in compiled version of code.

You can check official documentation for more descriptive explanation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

### <sup>Besides trying some type-inference analyses, re-casting et al,
 I would advise to</sup>
 build on rather an explicit testing:

Let's assume, there is some reasoning already made behind a designer's decision what is the minimum API version supported, and then, **each ZeroMQ `Socket` instance must provide an exception-free response** to each and every API-documented request:

```
try {
    var aLinger = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.LINGER     ); // ZMQ_LINGER
    var aCpuAfi = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.AFFINITY   ); // ZMQ_AFFINITY
    var aMaxMSZ = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.MAXMSGSIZE ); // ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE
    var aRecvBF = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.RCVBUF     ); // ZMQ_RCVBUF
    var aRecvWM = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.RCVHWM     ); // ZMQ_RCVHWM
    var aRecvTO = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.RCVTIMEO   ); // ZMQ_RCVTIMEO
    var aRecvMO = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.RCVMORE    ); // ZMQ_RCVMORE
    var aSendBF = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.SNDBUF     ); // ZMQ_SNDBUF
    var aSendWM = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.SNDHWM     ); // ZMQ_SNDBUF
    var aSendTO = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.SNDTIMEO   ); // ZMQ_SNDTIMEO
    var aFDESCR = inputUnderTest.getsockopt( zmq.FD         ); // ZMQ_FD

    console.log( 'Seems to match a ZeroMQ Socket instance.' );

}
catch (e){

    console.log( 'Was not a ZeroMQ Socket instance.' );

    }
}
```

Any failure to respond in an exception-free manner means:
either, an **`inputUnderTest` not being a ZeroMQ `Socket` instance** Q.E.D.
or
a ZeroMQ API-version or a language-specific binding/wrapper implementation has crept and was somehow silently changed behind our necks :o)

Either of which helps decide about our next steps.